# AngularJs: googlemap not displaying on partial view?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs and trying out some examples from github. There are some fundamentals I still don't understand well.

google's map is displayed when I tried this:

https://github.com/wbyoko/angularjs-google-maps-components/blob/master/01-Hello-Maps.html

But, when i tried in a SPA implementation. Move  to partials page, add routesProvider to load the partial, google map is not displaying anymore.

From the directives, i can see map object is returned from googleapi, but it just won't display the map object on the partial view.

---

map.html

```
<body ng-app="mapComponentsApp">

<div ng-view></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var mapApp = angular.module('mapComponentsApp', ['ngRoute']);

    mapApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$provide', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: '/angular/part-map.html',
    controller: 'MapCtrl'
  });
  }]);

mapApp.controller("MapCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
 console.log('mapctrl');
});

mapApp.directive('helloMaps', function () {
        var map, mapOptions;

        function initialize(id){
         mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.074688, -89.384294)
          };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(id), mapOptions);

        };

      return{
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.074688, -89.384294)
          };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(attrs.id), mapOptions);
        console.dir(map);
                  }

      }
    });  
  </script>
</body>
```

---

part-map.html

```
<h1>Hello Maps</h1>
<div hello-maps id="map-canvas"></div>
```

==================================

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you setting the `height` for your `map-canvas`?  I solve this problem for me by adding the following to my css:

```
#map-canvas {
    height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: I set it to height:100%

      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }

Do you have yours working in partial view?  If so, do you mind sharing your code? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the problem is your map variable is going out of scope?  If you put your code in a plunker, I can try to help.

Comment: thanks marcoseu. I will compare the code and try to figure them out. Thanks again.

Comment: I wonder if seting height of canvas solves the problem of SPA - i think it doesn't (but i'm still looking for solution